# How to access a Windows shared USB printer from Raspbian

Tags: printing, cups

I have a desktop box with Windows 8.1 with a Brother MFC-2740DW printer. I can access that print from mu laptop with Windows 10 without any problem. Now, I want to be able to do the same with my Rpasberry Pi 3 B (Raspbian Stretch). In order to achieve that I've followed the steps indicated in this tutorial with no results:

https://www.howtogeek.com/169679/how-to-add-a-printer-to-your-raspberry-pi-or-other-linux-computer/

1. Cups do not find any Network Printer
2. Using the `Windows Printer via SAMBA' option. First, I add the printer using the following address 'smb://local_computer/printer_name'. Then asks me to select  the driver  from a dropdown list but the driver of my printer is not there.

What do I need to do? How do I install more drivers in cups? Is it even a problem with the driver?

Comment: You need to install a (Linux) driver for your printer on Raspbian. Alternatively a Windows driver inside a wrapper if no Linux support is available.

Comment: If your printer supports PostScript, then generic drivers are most likely available.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print something, you have to solve two problems:

- You must generate data that the printer can understand. This is usually the task of the driver.
- You must be able to transmit the data to the printer.

A Google search for "MFC-2740DW" brings results for "MFC-L2740DW". It seems the printer supports PCL and PostScript.

Unfortunately, even the so called [Technical Information for Advanced Users](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/htmldoc/mfc/cv_dcpl2520dw/use/manual/index.html#GUID-56D08215-53BF-40AE-8CA0-49ED387D54AA_404) is low on details. My guess is that the printer can accept print jobs via LPD and uses queues named "PCL_P1" and "POSTSCRIPT_P1" for PCL and PostScript.

You can try to add a `lpd` destination and a generic PCL or PS driver to CUPS.